# Express & EJS - layout.ejs not used

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Im trying out EJS as a view engine with Express. It seems that my layout.ejs is not used. I have two views index.ejs and layout.ejs both in my 'views' folder. It seems that index.js is rendered but layout.ejs is not. The layout.ejs file should be including a CSS file but when the page is rendered in the browser this is not there. Any test test text that I place in the layout.ejs file is not output with the response.

Am I missing an additional configuration step?

Thanks!

My server.js code:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.get('/', function(req, res){
            res.render('index.ejs', {title: 'EJS Engine'});
    });

    app.listen(8080);
```

In my layout.ejs I am linking to a single css file which resides in the public folder.

layout.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <head>
           <title><%= title %></title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
       </head>
       <body>
              <%- body %>
       </body>
       </html>
```

index.ejs

```
<div id="container">
        index.html
</div>
```

Comment: Explicitly set the location for the views directory... defaults to CWD/views

Comment: i had to use express-partials to get support.

Comment: Isn't layout.ejs supposed to be used by the EJS view engine by default?

Comment: It uses layout.ejs in the /views directory by default. Else the location needs to be specified explicitly using app.set('views', __dirname + '/<location of layout.ejs>');

Comment: my layout.ejs is in the views directory.

Comment: @Nick "[*Currently EJS has no notion of blocks, only compile-time `include`s*](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs#layouts)." Layouts were otherwise a [feature of Express](http://expressjs.com/2x/guide.html#view-rendering) though 2.x. If you're using 3.x, from "[*View system changes*](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x)" -- "*To get back layout functionality with EJS you can use [express-partials](https://github.com/publicclass/express-partials) or [ejs-locals](https://github.com/RandomEtc/ejs-locals).*"

Comment: @JonathanLonowski OH: I must have been looking at an old tutorial. Want to make this your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the module you need:
https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-ejs-layouts

Do the following:

```
npm install express-ejs-layouts // install the layout module from the command line

var express = require("express")
    ,path = require('path')
    ,fs = require('fs')
    ,expressLayouts=require("express-ejs-layouts") // add this requirement
    , app = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(expressLayouts); // add this use()
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

Now the ejs engine should use your layout.

Comment: This answer helped me becouse i use Express 4 and multiple view folders.

Answer (score 2):

```
app.set('view options', { layout:'layout.ejs' });
```

Place layout.ejs into your views folder.
Alternately you can place layout.ejs into  views/layouts folder and then use

```
app.set('view options', { layout:'layouts/layout.ejs' });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue.  In my case I would rather use Jade but I have a requirement for a more "html" style template engine for a particular project. At first I considered express-partials or ejs-locals (as mentioned in a comment by Jonathan Lonowski) or even using html via the pipe or dot syntax within Jade templates (see [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/jade.md#pipe-text) for more information about that option and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094423/is-it-considered-bad-practise-to-use-html-in-jade) SO post).  I am not able to introduce the additional dependencies for express-partials and ejs-locals into this project.  These two projects do look good and might meet your needs.

If you do not want to use these projects, you can do something like the following:

views/layout-head.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>The title</title>
</head>
<body>
```

views/layout-foot.ejs

```
</body>
</html>
```

views/index.ejs (or any other page)

```
<% include layout-head %>
This is the index page - <%= title %>
<% include layout-foot %>
```

routes/index.js

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
}
```

This is not an optimal solution but it works.  Most of my application will be a single page app and I have some other restrictions I have to work within so this works for my needs.  This may not the best solution in many cases - especially if you have complex and/or changing layouts.