# Passing variable value to EJS layouts file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I understand how to pass variable values to EJS files:

```js
    res.render('pageName', {
      variable1,
      variable2
      }
```

but now I want to pass a value to the layout.ejs file. It defines the layout of the page but we dont actually call to render it. So how can a value be passed to it?

I have a banner that is to be displayed on top of all pages and admin needs to be able to edit it himself. I added the banner to the layout.ejs file and now I'm not sure how to pass value to it.

Any suggesstion? Or any other approach I should take to display the banner on all pages yet keep it editable by the admin from admin panel?

Comment: "but we dont actually call to render it." — You have to have some code *somewhere* that causes it to be used.

Comment: EJS automatically finds the layout.ejs file and renders the pages in it

Comment: That sounds unlikely. It seems more unlikely after I've searched through the documentation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036904/express-ejs-layout-ejs-not-used suggests you need to be explicit.